# Relationship shows up on contact page but is undefined in reports, searches, and exports

Tags: relationships

I have a database in which I have recorded relationships and they are not showing up on the relationship report, in searches, etc. In other cases the same type of relationship does show up. After investigating in the database directly I've found that the relationships which don't show up are not in the database either.  But they do show up on the contact page under the relationships tab.  How do I get those relationships to integrate into the database?

Comment: hi Kevin. pls add some screenshots. if they aren't in the db then they should not be on the page

Answer (score 1):

I realized what the issue was.  You must be very careful in defining the relationships - A to B vs B to A.  I had different relationships defined for B to A when the A to B and B to A were the same.  For example: if you have Employer and Employee defined, you don't need to define a separate relationship for Employee to Employer -- the system handles which one is A and which one is B.